# What does this symbol represent in Combinatorics and Probability?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, notation

What does this notation represent in Combinatorics and Probability?

What is $P(EF)$ ? Is this $P(E \cap F)$??

What is $\binom{48}{12,12,12,12}$?

Comment: In probability theory often $E\cap F$ is indeed abbreviated by $EF$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a multinomial coefficient.  It represents the number of ways you can line up 12 blue marbles, 12 red marbles, 12 green marbles, and 12 white marbles.

Its value is $\frac{48!}{12!\cdot 12!\cdot 12!\cdot 12!}$

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's the multinomial coefficient:

$$\dfrac{48!}{12!12!12!12!}$$

Answer (score 0):

It's a multinomial coefficient. Defined as 
$$\binom {48}{12,12,12,12}=\frac {48!}{12!12!12!12!}$$
More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Also useful for determining coefficients of terms in a multinomial expansion.
For instance, the multinomial coefficient above is also the coefficient of $a^{12}b^{12}c^{12}d^{12}$ in the expansion of $(a+b+c+d)^{48}$.